# Add additional properties for "select-object"?

Tags: powershell

I try to add additional properties to a `select-object` output. However, it got the following error?

> Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.

```
$c = @{a = "...","...","..."; b = "...","...","..."}
$files | 
% {
    $filepath = $_.fullname
    write-host $filepath
    $type = getType $_.name

    # The following statement works
    Import-Csv $_ | select $c[$type] | OUT-GRIDVIEW

    # The following doesn't work 
    Import-Csv $_ | select $c[$type] -property @{n="File"; e={$filepath}}| out-gridview
}
```

Comment: `select @($c[$type];@{n="File"; e={$filepath}})`

Comment: `"..."` denotes a variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `-Property` twice, implicitly with the positional parameter `$c[$type]` and explicitly with your calculated property. You need to combine your property list and the calculated property to a single array and pass that to the `-Property` parameter.

One way to do this is to use the expression @PetSerAl suggested in the comment to your question:

```
$files | % {
  $filepath = $_.fullname
  $type = getType $_.name

  Import-Csv $_ |
    select @($c[$type]; @{n="File";e={$filepath}}) |
    Out-GridView
}
```

However, I think it would be simpler to just include the calculated property in your original property list(s):

```
$c = @{
  a = "...", "...", "...", @{n='File';e={$_.FullName}}
  b = "...", "...", "...", @{n='File';e={$_.FullName}}
}
```

so you don't need to manipulate that list later on:

```
$files | % {
  $type = getType $_.Name
  Import-Csv $_ | select $c[$type] | Out-GridView
}
```